# Both the Diamond Symbol and the Badge for mods?

Tags: discussion, design, profile-page, moderators, display-names

I was glad when a new badge was introduced for the moderators to appear in their profile page because the diamond symbol was getting a bit outdated in design.

But why the diamond symbol is still shown alongside the badge in the profile page?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Isn't it time to make that diamond go away?

Comment: In comment, post(answer/question), close notice, etc.. . There is no Staff/Moderator badge. This diamond is the single point of identification we had for years.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

We do not gain anything by removing the diamond. It's a low impact signal to identify that someone has "mod-like" powers, and it's visible even if you are not visiting that users's profile.

Besides, if you take away their shiny diamond we'll have another wave of mod resignations in our hands. They only keep at it because of the bling.

Comment: "*someone has "mod-like" powers*" are they...omnimodent?

Comment: In case anyone doesn't know, the second paragraph is a joke.

Answer (score 7):

That blue "moderator" badge thing is only shown if you're actively visiting that moderator's profile. The diamond still serves as an easy indicator that this user has moderator abilities everywhere else on the site, such as when leaving a comment. We still need that diamond to show that it's a moderator leaving a comment, for example. The point of the "staff" and "moderator" badges on the profile is so that moderators and staff members can be more easily distinguished without having to make an API call to check if a certain user with a diamond is a moderator or staff member.